# Two-way binding to an array of basic data types

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, value-type

What would be the best way to bind an `ItemsControl` to an array of, say, `System.Double`s, while being able to push back changes to underlying element?

### Details

I'm using `ItemsControl` to provide user with a set of vertical guides. The underlying VM object provides the positions of these guides as a `double[]`. I bind this array to the `ItemsSource` and get my guides positioned correctly in the `ItemsControl` (using `Transform`). So far so good.

However, these guides need to be adjustable. The `ItemTemplate` of my `ItemsControl` provides a `Thumb` using which user can adjust the position of the guide. However, since the underlying element is an intrinsic type (a `double`), changes won't push back to the source obviously (or am I wrong?!)

I'm now heading in the direction of creating **DoubleByRef** class, i.e. which basically will be a `double` **class** with a member **Value** of type `double` (hoepfully that's clear, LOL). But just wanted to check with the community if there's something better.

Comment: As an array does not support change notifications, binding directly to a `double[]` would not be robust.  If the number of items is fixed, your proposed `DoubleByRef[]` would work, provided `DoubleByRef` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  If values may be added or removed, you'd need something like `ObservableCollection<DoubleByRef>`.

Comment: I see no MVVM tag, probably worth to check it.

Comment: @MikeStrobel: Thanks. Note that the problem is not with the collection type, but with the underlying element type. Even with an `ObservableCollection<double>`, how am I going to do two-way binding of individual elements?

Comment: @dotNET Right, you can't.  I was a bit more clear about that in my answer.

Comment: @MikeStrobel: yep, correct. I saw your answer after posting the comment. Thanks. So I'm more or less on the correct path.

Comment: @dotNET Yes, you'll need some kind of box/wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bind `ItemsSource` to a collection (or an array), an item container is generated for each element in the collection.  Each container's data context points to the corresponding element from the source collection, meaning any bindings within the item container use that element as its binding source.  While you can certainly set a two-way binding on any value that is accessible *via* the binding source, you cannot set a two-way binding on the source itself.  There would be no way to do this, as the binding is only aware of the element's *value*; it knows nothing of the collection containing the element.  As it does not know where that value came from, it has no way to replace it.  In fact, for a collection of value types like `double[]`, the binding source isn't even the *same* value that's in the array--it's a boxed copy.

The only way to make this work like you envisioned is to wrap the guideline values in some reference-typed wrapper, like your proposed `DoubleByRef`.  Then you will be able to set up a two-way binding to the wrapped value.

You potentially have another problem, which is that arrays do not support collection change notification.  If your number of values is always fixed, this may not be a problem for you, and you can just bind to a `DoubleByRef[]`. 
 However, if values can be added or removed, your values will need to be wrapped in a collection implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  An `ObservableCollection<DoubleByRef>` would work.

As a fun aside, WPF does include a `DoubleCollection`, but it doesn't actually solve the element binding problem, nor does it implement change notification.  Would you care to guess what it's used for?  Yep—guidelines!

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting it as answer. Even though I expected to see something built-in.  :)